# Backtick stopped working on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, geforce-experience

A few days ago my backtick key stopped working, oddly enough if I hold shift the '~' character outputs without an issue so I can confirm the key isn't dead.

Answer (score 1):

So if you're using nvidia shadowplay and you rehotkey your backtick with nvidia shadowplay enabled and you have desktop recording setup then your backtick will completely lose it's default functionality. To fix this either disable shadowplay, disable desktop recording in shadowplay or change your backtick hotkey to something else.

Comment: You're a wizard. I was trying to figure this out for ages.